# how to check 'go get <package>' installation status?

Tags: go

Is there any option for `go get` that can tell me whether it actually did anything?

For example, if the package X was already installed, I would like to know that `go get X` didn't perform any downloading/installation.

Comment: You could also just do what `go get` does, and look at the import path to see if there'a a package there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `go get -v`

Here's an example of get doing something vs not:

```
$ go get -v  github.com/peak6/envflag
github.com/peak6/envflag (download) # downloaded package
github.com/peak6/envflag # built package (I think)

$ go get -v  github.com/peak6/envflag
$ # nothing to do
```